# Increment to a value from 0 in 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I need to increment the value from 0 to 103551 in 5 seconds. Below is the logic I have used. But it's not incrementing to the required value within 5 secs

```
var counter = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

function incrementSeconds() {
    counter += 1;
    el.innerText = "Processing " + counter + " execution records";
    if(counter == 103551) {
        console.log(new Date());
    }
}

console.log(new Date());
var time = 103551/5000;
var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, time);
```

HTML

```
<div id='seconds-counter'> </div>
```

Comment: just out of curiosity - what is purpose, why can't you say, set var to 103551 with 5 seconds time out for example

Comment: OP probably wants to display the number counting up over time.

Answer (score 3):

Your math is a little off. 103551/5000 = 20.7102ms

1000ms = 1s, 5s = 5000ms, 5000/20.7102 = 240 iterations.

The equation you want to solve is 5000/x = numIterations

So x = 5000/numIterations

Note: Most browsers have a minimum number you can set in setInterval(), so you may need to increment by more than 1 each loop to count to 103551 in 5 seconds. Since this is an oddly specific problem I'm going to gues that this might be an assignment so will omit a full solution from this answer. Good luck!

Comment: I have changed my logic to `var iter = 103551/5000; var time = 5000/iter;` I didn't understand the logic behind it. It's not working

Comment: It's `var iter = 5000/103551` or `var time = 5000/103551`

Comment: Ok for `var time = 5000/103551` the value is around `0.04828538594508986` and still the counter is not completed in 5 secs

Comment: Did you read my entire response? SetInterval is not going to work with a value of 0.048 ms. You need to do some math on how much you increment by in your timed function.

Comment: according to [this source](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Minimum-Timer-Intervals-in-JavaScript.html) most browsers can only fire off a timed function once every 15~ ms on average, if you only increment by 1 each time, you're not even going to count higher than 500.

Comment: Instead of having your code change the interval at which the function is called, why not have it always fire off once every 50 ms, and then instead of incrementing by 1, you increment by a calculated value to get to your target value

Comment: Yes I got what u said. Thinking of some math for it. I did by incrementing some value for every one second thats ok. But showing a counter is far better than just showing a value

Comment: Another thing to note, most monitors can only refresh 60 times a second, so updating the number faster than that is pointless and a waste of CPU, since the computer isn't even going to be able to display every single value.